# php ajax bypass nested forms issue

Tags: php, ajax, forms, wordpress, nested-forms

I'm using wordpress and try to create a plugin for uploading files.
The thing is that the plugin appears on the publish and edit page which are basically two giant forms.
As long as I put something in these pages, I'm inside these forms.

So I'm stuck with nested forms.

The only solutions I can think of are:

1. have a form inside an iframe and get the $_FILES data from the public/edit page.
2. Have an element (jquery?) which reacts as a file input but is not a file input in order not to have to use a form while having the ability to retrieve the $_FILES data.
3. Keeping the nested forms and have a workaround to make them work and get the $_FILES data

Whatever the option, I can't find anything about it over the internet.

Any help?

Thank you.